# Windows Server / IIS 10 / ODBC issue

Tags: ms-access, iis, odbc

Our Intranet (Windows Server 2019 / IIS 10) is using a simple access database. In global.asa we connect to this database as it :

"strconn = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\inetpub\intranet\data.mdb"
set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open strconn"

Windows authentification is enable

When i connect to intranet with an admin account, it works perfectly, when i connect to intranet with a user account, the authentification window opens; it fails untill i login with an admin account

Strange behavior :  if i navigate once with an admin account on Intranet, all other users can navigate on Intranet (whatever the computer from) !!!!

The line that cause this issue is "conn.open strconn"

I checked the database file permission , ACEODBC.DLL permission , made a try with ODBC system data source, check with processmonitor if i could see an ACCESS DENIED, uninstall/install access databese engine...

Idea : It looks like admin create a file , users can modify this file , this would explain the situation; as a consequence i checked user permission on c:\temp , c:\windows\temp because the JETxxx.tmp file is created once, and stay untill idle timeout happen, which looks looks like my issue.

My work around is to setup IDLE Timeout to Zero, and open Intranet once with admin account.... this works only if we don't restart the server or IIS, we have to fix this.

I don't know how can i check what layer fail ?

i'm just desperate now.... it should be so simple....

Thank you

Comment: Access and Excel were not designed to be used in the context of IIS. I wrote about that in 2009 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/lexli/database-for-web-applications and Microsoft had many articles on that topic. You have to migrate to a product like SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

This suggests that the web server does not have create file rights in the folder where the mdb resides.

For Access to update data, then the folder in which the mdb (or newer accDB) exists will require full read/write rights, and ALSO file create rights. If a user (or the web server) opens the file, and can't create the so-called locking ".ldb" file, then the database will be opened as read only. This thus explains why who opens first effects the behavior of the site (the site can't create the locking file due to limited rights on that folder with the mdb file). So, the web server needs MORE then just read/write to the file in that folder - it also needs file create rights to enable the server to create the .ldb locking file).

This suggests that the web site may well need to use what is called "impersonation". That means you may well consider setting up a user for the web site that has been granted rights to the folder where the mdb resides.

(and you don't mention if the mdb file is on the same server as the web server or not).

And of course, the server may well not be part of the company domain.

So, often in place of opening up the folder rights to everyone?
A user can be created on the web server that is specific granted rights to JUST that folder (you don't want a web server being able to mess around with all folders and computers on your network - far too dangerous).

So, a user on the server can be created that is granted rights to JUST that folder. You then in app pool "advanced" settings use that newly created user:

e.g. here:

[image]

As suggested, Access is not all that great for use in a web site, and with so many free "server" based systems, then little need exists to use mdb files for database operations on a web site.

Answer (score 0):

I just discover that when a domain user access to Intranet i have a warning in system event logs : "5009, WAS, A process serving application pool 'IntranetAPPPOOL' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '880'. The process exit code was '0xffffffd."

After this error the navigator ask user to autenticate.

Answer (score 0):

I checked that DB folder and Temp JET folder are allowed (Full control) to domain users.

I made test with application identity as `Administrator` and as `AppPoolIdentity` with same result.

Application is classic ASP; it's a local website, hosted on the DC, using domain credentials for the users. This was running fine on Windows Server 2009 / IIS8. I can't change the DB kernel because this DB is in use for many applications.

I'm using Windows Authentication, anonymous access disabled, with two providers: "NTLM" and "Negotiate"; these are default options in `web.config`.

I just discover that when a domain user accesses the Intranet, the `connection.open` raises a warning in the system Event Logs:

> 5009, WAS, A process serving application pool 'IntranetAPPPOOL' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '880'. The process exit code was '0xffffffd.

This means that in the below simple code on `global.asa`:

```vb
Sub Session_OnStart
    strconn = "ODBC;DSN=MyDBdns;DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}"
    set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.open strconn
End sub
```

The `Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")` is not involved; the warning (`broken_pipe`) and the authentication request comes from `conn.open strconn`.

Comment: This doesn’t appear to be a solution, but rather a list of further troubleshooting steps you’ve taken to isolate the problem. This is useful. But it should be an edit to your original question, not posted as an answer. As is, it makes the casual community member think that you’ve already answered your question and don’t require further help.